# How can I have card content slide up on hover whilst maintaining height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I am creating a UI with image cards, and I want to have the card content slide up on hover.

The trouble is that the card content will vary in height, so the card needs to be able to grow vertically, and images may not all be the same size, so they probably need to be set as background images with `background-size: cover;`.

I have tried to use absolution positioning on the `.card-hover` div, but this collapses the card height, so this is not possible.

Here is the code:-

```
<section class="people">
        <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="card" style="background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/600')">
                    <div class="card-hover">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Jane Doe</h4>
                            <h5 class="card-subtitle">Managing Director</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu
                                orci
                                non
                                erat eleifend pellentesque. Proin eleifend libero in risus viverra venenatis.</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Donec interdum turpis sit amet dapibus fringilla. Mauris volutpat
                                suscipit
                                ullamcorper. Sed elementum, odio sit amet molestie congue, arcu nunc tempus nisl,
                                vel
                                auctor
                                tellus urna ac orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam
                                sit
                                amet
                                eros elementum odio sagittis commodo.</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Vestibulum hendrerit aliquam nunc, vitae fermentum est finibus ac.
                                Vivamus
                                porta velit id tempus hendrerit.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer row no-gutters">
                            <div class="col text-left p-0">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="card-link"><i
                                                class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>test@domain.com</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fas fa-phone fa-fw"></i>+44 (0)123
                                            456
                                            7890</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="card-link"><i class="fas fa-mobile fa-fw"></i>+44 (0)123
                                            456
                                            7890</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col text-right p-0 align-self-end">
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                    <li class="list-inline-item m-0">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <span class="fa-stack fa-stack-lg" style="vertical-align: top;">
                                                <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-3x"></i>
                                                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                            </span></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item m-0">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <span class="fa-stack fa-stack-lg" style="vertical-align: top;">
                                                <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-3x"></i>
                                                <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                            </span></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and scss

```
.people {
    .card {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center top;
      color: #fff;

        .card-hover {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;

            &:hover {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            .card-body {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                padding: 20px;

                .card-title {
                    font-size: 1.75rem;
                    padding-bottom: 12px;
                    margin-bottom: 1rem;

                    &:before {
                        left: 50%;
                        margin-left: -30px;
                    }
                }

                .card-subtitle {
                    &:before {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    margin-bottom: 1rem;
                }

                .card-text {
                    font-weight: 300;
                    font-size: 0.8125rem;
                    text-align: left;
                }
            }

            .card-footer {
                border-radius: 0;
                border-top: none;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                background-color: transparent;

                li {
                    a {
                        color: #f1f1f;

                        i {
                            color: #fff;
                            margin-right: 5px;
                        }

                        .fa-stack-lg {
                            height: 3em;
                            line-height: 3em;
                            width: 3em;
                        }

                        .fa-stack {
                            i {
                                color: #fff;

                                &:hover {
                                    color: #f1f1f1;
                                }
                            }

                            .fa-stack-3x {
                                font-size: 2.5rem;
                                left: 0;
                                position: absolute;
                                text-align: center;
                                width: 100%;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it on Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/leecolarelli/pen/QWLKKKP)

I want to be able to maintain the cards height (defined by the card content) whilst having the content slide up. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It takes just too long to read the whole long text in your question, so if I got your point, pls check this jsfiddle

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: orange;
}

.inner {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.outer:hover > .inner {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry no, you have set height and width, not responsive.